# How to get actual size of image in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Hi i am trying to make my own map system for some game. I used

```
drawImage()
```

to insert a map and now i am trying to mark certain spots on that map. For example i would like to mark exact middle of the map or right bottom of the map. As you can see i marked x,y 1000,1000 but it is nowhere near the middle so i need to know the actual size of that image to do this. Is there a method that could do that? I tried logging out a context, but everything in it is client size 600 to 600. So i just need width and height of that image to calculate coordinates.
Here is the pen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQQpBe

Comment: You want to get the size of the img? Or the size of the canvas? The size of the image you can use: document.getElementById('map').width

Comment: i want to get size of the image IN canvas the image sizes are different in canvas than  outside canvas

Comment: If you delete the width and height attributes of your image you can get the size of the image using `img.width` and `img.height`. Also when you draw the image you can decide it's size with `context.drawImage(img, 0, 0,width,height);`

Answer (score 0):

When you drawImage() on Canvas you just write pixel instead of other pixel. Canvas can't provide x and y.

So if you want to do that you have to store coordinates of your image, width,height... Depend on what you want to do.

Canvas just allow you to draw and make transformation like translation, scale ...